# Do I really need proxy for handling node.js?

Tags: node.js, proxy, nginx, websocket

I'm going to use Socket.IO to handle websockets or XHR-polling to implement a realtime app

which is on the top of node.js.

Many people are so into proxying their node.js server and

I don't understand the true meaning of proxy except security reasons.

Is there other reason to set proxy to handle node?

I'm currently using nginx 1.1 as a webserver and proxy server.

Unfortunately, I have found that nginx 1.1 can support HTTP 1.1 but not websockets.

Should I just use Socket.IO without proxying?

Or If I really need to do it so, how can I set up proxying websockets with nginx or other alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have noticed that you can only run *one* server on any given TCP port. If you want to use node.js *and* any other web server, then you'll want to have a proxy server to send client requests to the correct backend server.

Comment: I just want to simply use socket.mysite.com for using socket.IO and assign different IP for that domain. In this case, do I still need proxy for socket.mysite.com?

Comment: If you're running node.js on port 80 its *own* IP address (and no other web server on port 80), then no, you don't require a proxy. However, one might still be useful for rate limiting or access control.